# Android:Canvas and onTouchListener

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

I have an application which has a canvas where I can draw free hand stuff. Now, I would want to display a toast message on the MotionEvent.KEY_UP event which can be handled in the onTouchListener handler. As of now I've used console or System.out.println to display my message. The application force closes if I use Toast. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this on the UI thread.

Look at this: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Comment: my canvas is an instance of a class that extends from SurfaceView and  implements SurfaceHolder.Callback. Note that this instance is running in a separate thread

Comment: create a Handler and post a runnable